# trying to implement an array within an array of of objects

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iife

In Google Apps JS. I would like to implement an array of objects, each with properties and methods.  One of the properties needs to be an array of objects and I would like to be able to access this array by  using methods in the parent array.

So far my best efforts is:

```
function myFunction () {
  var teamNo = 3;
  var allNames =["n1","n2","n3","n4"] ;
  var createnames = function () {
    var names = [];            
    for ( var j = 0; j <=3 ; j ++) {      
      (function (j) {
        var localNames = ["local1-names"+j,"local2-names"+j];
        names[j] = (function (player){
          return {
            namArr: localNames,
            name:   allNames[j],         
            addName: (function (player){
              localNames.push(player);
            }) (player),
             team:   teamNo            
          };         
        });
      }) (j);
    }
    return names;
  }
  var myname = createnames();
  var foo = myname[0]().namArr;
  var foo1 = myname[1]().namArr;
  myname[1]().addName("added");
  var foo2 = myname[1]().namArr;
  var foo3 = myname[2]().namArr;
  var debug = true;
}
```

As soo as I add the code to implement the sub array I get a runtime error saying that addName does not exist.

Comment: This looks like a great example of why one shouldn't nest IIFEs in their code.

Comment: You are also creating functions in a loop. Never a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're invoking this immediately:

```
addName: (function (player) {
    localNames.push(player);
})(player)
```

instead of assigning it:

```
addName: function (player) {
    localNames.push(player);
}
```

Also, each `names[]` function takes a `player`, and so does the `addPlayer()` function, making the `names[]` parameter unreachable. If you're not going to pass anything to the `names[]` functions, then remove the parameter.

And I'd suggest using named functions instead of inlined IIFEs.

Comment: Thanks,  I had tried that previously but a bug in the code led me to think I needed another closure around addPlayer . It now works OK.

Comment: Re comments about iife's. I am new to JS and have read that this technique allows you to implement with good data hiding.  What is the advantage of named functions and can my design goals be met with them?

Comment: @user1812645: Advantage is code clarity. Any time you need to create functions in a loop for the purpose of variable scope, I would use a named function instead of an IIFE. So for example, to eliminate the IIFE in the `for` loop, I'd do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/u9Vg3/1/